# Two methods should do the same thing, but do not

Tags: java

I have two methods which are supposed to do the same thing, but only one of them is working. I am having trouble spotting why one works and the other does not.

Method 1:

```
Coordinate processHeadDirectionCoordinate(String directionArrow) {      
            switch(directionArrow) {
            case "U":       
                direction = new Coordinate(0,-1);       
                return direction;  
            case "R":       
                direction = new Coordinate(1, 0);
                return direction;
            case "L":
                direction = new Coordinate(-1, 0);
                //direction = adjustedCoordinate;       
                return direction;
            case "D":
                direction = new Coordinate(0, 1);
                //direction = adjustedCoordinate;
                return direction;
            }       
            return direction;  
        }
```

Method 2:

```
Coordinate processHeadDirectionCoordinate(String directionMoved) {    
        ArrayList<String> arrayListString = new ArrayList<String>();            
        arrayListString.add("U");
        arrayListString.add("R");
        arrayListString.add("L");
        arrayListString.add("D");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayListString.size(); i++) {
            if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
                direction = new Coordinate(0,-1);    
                return direction;    
            }               
            if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
                direction = new Coordinate(1,0);    
                return direction;    
            }               
            if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
                direction = new Coordinate(-1,0);    
                return direction;    
            }               
            if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
                direction = new Coordinate(0, 1);    
                return direction;
            }    
        }
        return direction;    
    }
```

Both methods are supposed to take a string consisting of ("U", "L", "D", or "R") and depending on which one I have, will determine on how I modify a set of coordinates (direction).

Method 2 (does not work). I simply create an array list of ("U", "L", "D", "R") then input directionArrow (which is either "U", "L", "D", or "R") and cycle through a for loop to check which if statement is satisfied.

Method 1 is supposed to do the same thing, but this time, I use switch statements.

I am wondering why Method 1 works, but method 2 does not?

Comment: I hope you do understand that your second method makes no sense at all and very likely won't do what you assume it does?

Comment: Why do you think it will work?

Comment: No they should not work the same. Your logic in the second is completely wrong. Having the exact same `if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved))`  4 times behind each other with a return on each doesn't make sense. Your if blocks 2-4 can never be entered because if they would the first one would also have been entered and have already returned.  If I understand what you are trying to do here, simply using a `Map<String, Coordinate>` might be an actual solution to your problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies guys. Yes I think I see where the logic is going wrong here. So I guess in this instance, using some sort of array is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you [already see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70111704/507738) what went wrong here.

It *could* have worked if the `for` loop would have been rewritten to this:

```java
Coordinate[] coords = {
    new Coordinate(0, -1),
    new Coordinate(1, 0),
    new Coordinate(-1, 0),
    new Coordinate(0, 1)
}; // Or a List<Coordinate>
for (int i = 0; i < arrayListString.size(); i++) {
    if (arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {
        direction = coords[i];
        return direction;
    }
}
```

But this code effectively uses two separate arrays to search for a letter and provide the appropriate Coordinate.

As OH GOD SPIDERS already said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111538/two-methods-should-do-the-same-thing-but-do-not#comment123937871_70111538), you're better off using a map. A map maps a key to a value.

```java
Map<String, Coordinate> map = Map.of(
    "U", new Coordinate(0, -1),
    "R", new Coordinate(1, 0),
    "L", new Coordinate(-1, 0),
    "D", new Coordinate(0, 1)
);
```

```java
Coordinate processHeadDirectionCoordinate(String directionMoved) {
    Coordinate c = map.get(directionArrow);
    if (coordinate != null) {
        direction = c;
    }
    return direction;
}
```

---

But your `switch` statement is also fine, although since newer Java versions, it could be replaced by a *switch expression*:

```java
Coordinate processHeadDirectionCoordinate(String directionMoved) {
    return direction = switch (directionMoved) {
        case "U" -> new Coordinate(0, -1);
        case "R" -> new Coordinate(1, 0);
        case "L" -> new Coordinate(-1, 0);
        case "D" -> new Coordinate(0, 1);
        default -> direction;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the method 2, your for statement is not really doing what you want. If you think about it, you are always going to return *new Coordinate(0,-1)*

```
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayListString.size(); i++) {
        if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
            direction = new Coordinate(0,-1);    
            return direction;    
        }               
        if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
            direction = new Coordinate(1,0);    
            return direction;    
        }               
        if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
            direction = new Coordinate(-1,0);    
            return direction;    
        }               
        if(arrayListString.get(i).equals(directionMoved)) {    
            direction = new Coordinate(0, 1);    
            return direction;
        }    
    }
```

Your if statements are all the same. That means, in the moment *arrayListString.get(i)* matches what you passed in *directionMoved* , the first if will be true and return that *Coordinate(0,-1)*